# loading uiwebview from specified location

Tags: ios4, uiwebview

```
//Move to bookmarked place if page is opened from bookmark section.
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView1;
{
if(chkview == 2)
{
    //Move webview to chkScrollValue position.
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.scrollTop = %d", chkScrollValue]];

   // [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scrollBy(0,%d);",chkScrollValue]];
}
}
```

I'm loading my webview which was displaying html which was in resources folder and it was working fine. Now, i'm using javascript with html and this is not working anymore.

Comment: Is this webview scrollable? what's overflow attribute of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. I was performing this task after `webViewDidFinishLoad`. Rather than that now I added another function and added this code in function

`[self performSelector:@selector(loadBookmark) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.4]`;